# Not showing RSVP buttons in email - ical-generator

Tags: calendar, gmail, icalendar

Not getting RSVP buttons in the email. I'm using "ical-generator" NPM to generate ics file.

This is code to generate ics file

```
let eventObj = {
    method: 'request',
    start: new Date(startTime),
    end: new Date(endTime),
    summary: "testing meeting",
    uid: uid,
    sequence: 0,
    description: description,
    organizer: {
        name: fullname,
        email: email
    },
    attendees:[
        {
            mailto : 'user@gmail.com',
            email : 'user@gmail.com',
            name : 'john',
            status : 'needs-action',
            rsvp : true,
            type : 'individual'
        }
    ],
    status: 'confirmed'
}
let cal = ical();
cal.domain(url).name('My ical invite');
cal.createEvent(eventObj);
```

my ics file will look like below

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
NAME:My ical invite
X-WR-CALNAME:My ical invite
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5f44e98484341386e4523ba1@dominname
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20200825T103548Z
DTSTART:20200826T183000Z
DTEND:20200826T190000Z
SUMMARY:testing meeting
DESCRIPTION:meeting Description : testing
ORGANIZER;CN="peter":mailto:user1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP
 =TRUE;CN="john";EMAIL=user@gmail.com:MAILTO:user@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

in my mail, I'm getting ics like below (I'm using gmail)
[image]

Here I'm not getting RSVP buttons and also in my ics file 'METHOD:REQUEST' is missing.

could you please help me out of this

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I place 'method' in the wrong place

it should be here

```
let cal = ical()
cal.method('REQUEST')
cal.domain(url).name('My ical invite')
```

Now I'm able to get RSVP button on email

Comment: Can you plese help me  can you send me the code you used to generate Ical string from ical generator, I am also not getting rsvp buttons

Comment: you can find that in the question itself @IrfanKhan